# Get location info from a Instagram link

Tags: java, api, instagram

Can I get the information from a Instagram link such as : https://instagram.com/p/7u46R_Ia9X/ 
I found we can get the information with location id with Instargram API but I dont know to get location ID or location info from a link like above.
Thank you so much

Update:We can resolve with under answer, if you dont have a Access token , we can receive with simple link :
http://bobmckay.com/web/simple-tutorial-for-getting-an-instagram-clientid-and-access-token/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the `media-id` value for the image, and then use the following endpoint to get the  `location-id` and other related info.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

The response of this end point returns the location along with all the details of the media.

**Code to get the media id from an instagram url in JS**

```
$.ajax({     
    type: 'GET',     
    url: 'http://api.instagram.com/oembed?callback=&url=http://instagram.com/p/Y7GF-5vftL‌​/',     
    cache: false,     
    dataType: 'jsonp',     
    success: function(data) {           
        try{              
            var media_id = data[0].media_id;          
        }catch(err){}   
    } 
});
```